# How does the "Animate Objects" spell work?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, animated-objects

I have the following questions concerning the spell "[animate objects](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/animateObjects.html)":

1. It seems clear that this spell gives objects a mode of movement which they didn't have before. What kind of movement does it give? Can objects walk, slide, roll, fly, etc.? What if the object doesn't have moving parts?
2. Do animated objects act independently of the caster? I assume so, since otherwise, the spell would say something about requiring concentration. Are they treated like summoned animals - attacking enemies and/or obeying orders if possible? Can they refuse the will of the caster - do they avoid placing themselves in suicidal (?) conditions?
3. How do animated objects determine the enemy so that they can attack? Do they have blindsight or some similar ability? How far does it extend? Do they simply divine where they need to go? If so, are there any limits to their ability to divine locations?
4. Can animated objects be debuffed in any meaningful way? Can they acquire status conditions aside from "broken" and the like (i.e., conditions that apply specifically to objects)?
5. How are attack and damage determined for animated objects? Is it related to the caster level, ability modifier, etc.? Can animated objects do anything but move, attack and full attack? When full attacking, do objects get iterative attacks?

I would be happy to ask these questions separately if desired; I put them together since I didn't see any other questions about this spell.

Comment: FWIW I think that these are all such closely-related questions that they're really the same question asked from different angles. I think that makes them suited for a single question-post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Spell description for reference](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/animateObjects.html#_animateitems)

> It seems clear that this spell gives objects a mode of movement which
>   they didn't have before. What kind of movement does it give? Can
>   objects walk, slide, roll, fly, etc.? What if the object doesn't have
>   moving parts?

By default, It will have a land movement. How this movement is executed will depend on his alotment of mobile parts. If the original object has no moving parts, it will  achieve mobility by other means. (A [stone golem](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/monsterAdvancement.html), as a example, is created from a statue sculpted from a single block of stone, and yet it gains joints after it is animated). Also, you can add other movement modes when deciding its characteristics.

> Do animated objects act independently of the caster? I assume so,
>   since otherwise, the spell would say something about requiring
>   concentration. Are they treated like summoned animals - attacking
>   enemies and/or obeying orders if possible? Can they refuse the will of
>   the caster - do they avoid placing themselves in suicidal (?)
>   conditions?
>
> How do animated objects determine the enemy so that they
>   can attack? Do they have blindsight or some similar ability? How far
>   does it extend? Do they simply divine where they need to go? If so,
>   are there any limits to their ability to divine locations?

The caster select the target these objects will attack at the moment of casting the spell (he can change that target later, as a move action). The animated objects are considered summoned monsters of the construct subtype, so they are subject to the general rules of summoned monsters. Note that, as per the spell description, attacking their target is all the monster that created will do (standard summon spells, for example, says that monster can perform other actions apart from attacking). Likewise, choosing  is The caster can choose a different target as a move action, but has otherwise no other form of control over them. This is how they determine who they can attack, it is all detailed in the spell description.

As for how they see, they are treated as summoned monsters of the construct type, and As [constructs](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/creatureTypes.html#_construct), they have low ligth vision and darkvision (60ft) by default.

> Can animated objects be debuffed in any meaningful way? Can they
>   acquire status conditions aside from "broken" and the like (i.e.,
>   conditions that apply specifically to objects)?

Animated objects cannot gain the broken status because they are considered constructs, and thus creatures, rather than items. They can be debuffed, disabled  or impaired the same way any you can do with any other creature,  barring construct-specific [inmunities and resistances](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/creatureTypes.html#_construct). Note also that animated objects created with the spell are vulnerable to dispelling and antimagic.

> How are attack and damage determined for animated objects? Is it
>   related to the caster level, ability modifier, etc.? Can animated
>   objects do anything but move, attack and full attack? When full
>   attacking, do objects get iterative attacks?

The link given by Wyrmwood shows the stat block of a medium sized animated object, and its many options. Depending on those options, and after size changes, if applicable ([see here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/monsterAdvancement.html)), you will have animated object with different characteristics, that may include multiple attacks. Increasing caster level do not advance the creatures, it allows you to animate more of them, or animate bigger ones.

Answer (score 8):

Reading the monster entry might help. 
http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/animatedObject.html#_animated-object

The 3.5 Player's Handbook makes the reference to the Monster Manual entry, but the SRD does not. I guess since Pathfinder uses the SRD it was an oversight. On Jans Carton's hypertext d20, he links the word animated object to the monster entry, though the text does not mention anything.

Comment: +1 Ah, didn't think to check there. I'll read it and edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: How strange that the spell does not reference this at all... Though the creature type does!