# Using the spell animate object, how do you determine the amount of construction points you can use?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, constructs

Awhile ago [someone else posted a question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91986/23058) about animate object used on a weapon and got me interested in this.

There seem to be 3 pages I can find that talk about animate object.

The first is the spell [animate object](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-objects). Second is [animated objects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/animated-object). Third is [building and modifying constructs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/building-and-modifying-constructs).

Now I have no interest in building permanent constructs and want to use the spell, but no where on the 3 pages does it mention what the construction points (CP) are suppose to be when using the spell. The other methods are clear in their construction, pricing, and abilities.

The second page (animate objects) has a table which mentions constructs of different sizes and the CP they are suppose to have, **but**

> Animated objects have a number of Construction Points (CP) used to purchase abilities and defenses in addition to those presented above. A medium animated object has 2 CP; differently sized objects have CP totals as detailed on the size chart on this page. **If an animated object spends more CP than its size category would allow, its CR increases by 1 (minimum of +1) for every 2 additional CP spent.**

So according to this, when using the spell (and thus not paying for it) my constructs can have any amount of CP I want and the CR raises. None of the sources mention a cap or limit based on caster level or something. So how does it all work?

There is a related question, [located here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30973/23058) which gives me some movement and vision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spell animate objects says:

> **Targets** one Small object per caster level; see text

and

> You may animate one Small or smaller object or a corresponding number of larger objects as follows: A Medium object counts as two Small or smaller objects, a Large object as four, a Huge object as eight, a Gargantuan object as 16, and a Colossal object as 32.

Therefore your caster level determines the size/number of animated objects you can create.

Per the table in the Animated Objects section of the Bestiary, that translates into CP based on size.  So for you creating animated objects via the spell, those are the points you have to spend on special abilities for the constructs you make.  If you're 12th level you can make, say, three Large objects (per the spell) each with 3 CP (per the Bestiary entry).

Now, the spell animate object is not the only way to get animated objects. They are also just plain monsters that a GM places.  If a GM gives them a bunch more powers, then they should boost their CR.  That's all that section that states "If an animated object spends more CP than its size category would allow" is saying. It's not directed to you, it's to the GM.

Comment: I figured that was the case, but as a more powerful caster why cant I get a smaller construct with more abilities than just larger ones?

Comment: Because some game designer didn't want the headache of trying to balance that.